# ModelMapper - condition AND provider

Tags: conditional-statements, modelmapper

All -

I'm trying to do an "addmapping" with a condition and a provider... bottom line is, one of my values are an Instant, and without the provider, it blows up telling me that Instant doesnt have a default constructor (which it doesnt)

I've gotten this far:

.addMappings(mapper -> {

```
            mapper.when(ctx -> customerSource(ctx).getEnableDuplicatePOChangedTime().isDirty())
                .<Instant>map(src -> src.getEnableDuplicatePOChangedTime().getValue(), (dest, v) -> dest.setEnableDuplicatePOChangedTime(v));  

            mapper.with(req -> req.getSource()).<Instant>map(src -> src.getEnableDuplicatePOChangedTime().getValue(), (dest, v) -> dest.setEnableDuplicatePOChangedTime(v));
```

})

However, what seems to happen now is, it skips the condition all together - it maps it no matter what!

In debug, this seems to overwrite the condition, setting it to null.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

well, I seemed to figure it out by using a provider up front, and getting rid of the add mappings.... so it would be something like this

```
.setProvider(request -> {
                    CustomerPreferencesDirty source = CustomerPreferencesDirty.class.cast(request.getSource());
                    PreferencesByCustomer dest = new PreferencesByCustomer();
                    if (source.getEnableDuplicatePOChangedTime().isDirty()) {
                        dest.setEnableDuplicatePOChangedTime(source.getEnableDuplicatePOChangedTime().getValue());
                    return dest;
                })
```

and then I continue on with addMappings for properties other than this one.... I'm good with that.